# What is the meaning of init method in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I am  new in objective c and from java background, I want to know what is the meaning of `init()` method/function in objective c in a base class while achieving inheritance ? 
Is this a kind of constructor like in java? Is it essential to use only `init()` method for creating and using objects? Can we use other methods also instead of using `init()`?

And at last, why is the return type of the `init()` is `id` ?

Comment: Googled first buddy.

Comment: Refer link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: read carefully this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210) before get started with objective c.

Comment: return type of `init` is already `instancetype`. It was `id` long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if it's objective c, it's init and not init() :) just saying... kinda big things...
See in java, when you are doing a

```
new MyClass()
```

2 things happened:

- the compiler book some space in memory to store your new instance
- the MyClass constructor is called.

now, in objective-C, those 2 thing are separated into 2 methods:
 - alloc
 - init

so when you do want to make a new object, you have to call these  2 methode

```
MyClass * a = [MyClass alloc]; // this will return a pointer to a space in memory big enough to store an instance of MyClass
a = [a init]; // this will call the init method on a and return the pointer initialized with all iVar to 0 plus whatever you did by yourself in the init method.
```

usually, it's done in one line

```
MyClass * a = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

That's why it is so convenient to have init a instance class that returns the actual instance